# Magento installing different modules to those stated in composer.json

Tags: magento2, module, composer, version

I have successfully updated to 2.4.3 and in doing so have upgraded a number of modules. For some reason, however, Magento is ignoring the module versions stated in the composer:

Two modules for example:

**"feefo/reviews": "1.4.2",**

**"stripe/stripe-payments": "2.9.5",**

This matches version in the composer.lock file also. But once I install (composer install, `bin/magento setup:upgrade`, `bin/magento setup:di:compile` etc) and look directly in
**vendor/feefo/reviews/etc/module.xml** I still see module **version 1.2**.

Likewise, if I look in **vendor/stripe/stripe-payments/etc/module.xml** I see **version 2.8.3**

There are no errors or logs during installation but I have no idea why this would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are aware and did already consider this, but just in case: The version stated in module.xml does not *necessarily* match the composer package version. Composer does not rely on the module.xml version tag but on the one in the package's own composer.json. Did you check those?

Comment: I checked those and there are still differences. Feefo modules composer version states 1.4.2 but the module.xml says 1.2.0. Still not sure if they are actually supposed to match.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the module versions are being overridden by another dependency or module that is being installed or updated at the same time.

You can try to run composer why feefo/reviews and composer why stripe/stripe-payments to see if any other modules or dependencies require an older version of these modules.

If that's the case, you can try to update or remove the conflicting modules/dependencies or reach out to their developers for a solution.

Alternatively, you can try to manually update the module versions by modifying the module.xml files in the vendor directory, but keep in mind that this is not recommended and may cause compatibility issues or conflicts with future updates.